# How do I make a function to accept an argument that is another function?

Tags: python, function

My question might seem confusing but it is the only way I could think of wording it. I apologise for any confusion, I will try my best to explain.

Basically what I am trying to do is have a simple exit function within my game that asks "Do you want to exit?" If the user inputs no it returns them back to a function they were in.

Here is what I have tried to do however it seems to just be looping back to the 'bear_room()' function.

```
def bear_room():

    print "You are greeted by a bear"
    next = raw_input()

    if next == 'fight':
        print 'You tried to fight a bear. You died'
    elif next == 'exit':
        exit_game(bear_room())
    else:
        print 'I did not understand that!'
        bear_room()

def exit_game(stage):

    print '\033[31m Are you sure you want to exit? \033[0m'

    con_ext = raw_input(">")

    if con_ext == 'yes':
        exit()
    elif con_ext == 'no':
        stage
    else:
        print 'Please type ''yes'' or ''no'
        exit_game()
```

Comment: Just an aside: naming a variable `next` will shadow the builtin `next` - so you may wish to consider changing the name - perhaps `next_room` for instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it; you just need to not call `bear_room` when you're passing it as an argument:

```
    elif next == 'exit':
        exit_game(bear_room)
```

Conversely, you need to call `stage` as a function:

```
    elif con_ext == 'no':
        stage()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between passing a function around and calling it.

Here you are copying a reference to the function `raw_input` into the variable `next`, without actually executing it. You probably want to add parentheses `()` to `raw_input`:

```
next = raw_input
```

Here you are calling `bear_room()` again, recursively, instead of passing a reference to it to the `exit_game` function. You probably want to remove the parentheses `()` to `bear_room`:

```
elif next == 'exit':
    exit_game(bear_room())
```

Again, mentioning a function without parentheses does not execute it, so you want to add those here too:

```
elif con_ext == 'no':
    stage
```